# In Rails what is the best way to get global data for specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, request

I have to get some data from database when user sends a request (doesn't matter what request). It is just a functionality where user will see how many 'somethings' he has in a main menu. It would be perfect to load this data when user signs in, but most of the time user only signs in once and checks the 'Remember me' checkbox, so I can't put it there.

The only solution that I can think of is to put this in the `ApplicationController` but I would like to avoid doing it and having unnecesary requests. Is there any better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Would storing this information in the session hash be acceptable?

Comment: That could be a nice solution, but this information can change and probably will be different in each day. So if I understand the solution with session, if the user won't logout and sign in again and rebuild session this information still will be the same.

Comment: If this information can change, on the request that updates the information you can update the information in the session as well? If it's not that simple and there are other factors that update this information, maybe having some check in a before filter to check for updates is the best solution?

Comment: Yeah, I think I will store it in a session hash and also keep a date there. Every day I will check if the date is different and then change this information. Thanks for the tip! :)